# passing arguments to docker exec from bash prompt and script

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, shell, docker

I am trying to execute a command inside my mongodb docker container. From my linux command prompt it is pretty easy and works when I do this

```
docker exec -it d886e775dfad mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'
```

The above tells me to go to a container and execute the command

```
"mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()' - This tells mongo to take rs.isMaster() as an input and execute it. This works and gives me the output.
```

Since I am trying to automate this via bash script, I did this

```
cmd="mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()"
```

And then tried executing like this

```
docker -H $node2 exec d886e775dfad "$cmd"
```

But I guess somehow docker thinks that now the binary file inside the container is not mongo or sth else and it gives me the following error:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Answer (score 27):

```
docker exec -it d886e775dfad sh -c "mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'"
```

This calls the shell (`sh`) executing the script in quotation marks. 
Note that this also fixes things like wildcards (*) which otherwise do not work properly with docker exec.

Comment: Can you explain why your solution works in order to raise the value of your contribution? Posting only code is often not very helpful.

Comment: Why is `-c` not listed in `docker exec --help`?

Comment: @Caleb it's a parameter to `sh`

Comment: Oh! Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to run (there's a missing single quote in your example):

```
cmd="mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'"
```

Followed by (without the quotes around `$cmd`):

```
docker -H $node2 exec d886e775dfad $cmd
```

By including quotes around `$cmd` you were looking for the executable file `mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'` rather than the executable `mongo` with args `mongo`, `--eval`, and `'rs.isMaster()'`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though mongo is interpreting the entire contents of `$cmd` as the command to execute. This makes sense because you are quoting the parameter on the command line. Essentially when you did `... exec "$cmd"` the shell will interpret the dollar-sign and expand it to be the contents in-place. Next it will interpret the double-quotes and pass the entire inner contents (now being `mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'` as a single command line argument to the process. This should result in mongo looking for a program with the name `mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()` in your path. Which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: how do i fix this?

Comment: Oops sorry forgot the solution. Try omitting the quotes around the variable. Then it should expand the variable inline and turn into `docker -H $node2 exec d886e775dfad mongo --eval 'rs.isMaster()'`